# Content does not stay in Grid Wrapper; Fixed Sidebar for bigger screens

Tags: css, layout, grid, navbar, css-grid

I'm trying to make a simple responsive layout for a webpage,
and encountered two problems:

1. I'm trying make the sidebar(containing header,nav and footer) a fixed bar when using a screen bigger than 660px in width.
2. When stretching the screen to 800px, I noticed the dummy text I put into the main container overflows.

   Here's part of the code:

   ```
   .wrapper{ display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;}
   ```

full code:

https://codepen.io/Aeshtray/pen/GvPdoQ/

And a screenshot about what I meant by overflowing content:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXtrz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `overflow: auto;` on the `.main` class

Answer (score 0):

ok. Main container is with fixed size so it will not expand with text. You just need to give main div `overflow-y: auto;`. Updated code here [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqRxZm)